# Angularjs namespaced controller in coffeescript

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, karma-runner

How can I test an angularjs controller written in coffeescript in a karmatest?

I keep getting the following error in the test:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'App.PhoneListCtrl(scope)') at /home/rolf/projects/web/stylus/coffee/test/unit/controller.spec.js:8

my controller looks like the following:

```
'use strict'                                                                               
### Controllers ###                                                                        
App = App or {}                                                                            

class App.PhoneListCtrl                                                                    
  constructor: ($scope) ->                                                               
     $scope.phones = [{                                                                 
         'name':"nexus S"                                                               
         'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S'                                 
         },                                                                             
         {'name': "Motorola XOOM&reg;",                                                 
         'snippet': "The next next generation tablet"                                   
         },                                                                             
         {'name': "Motorola XOOM&reg; with WiFi",                                       
         'snippet': "The next next generation tablet"                                   
         }                                                                              
     ]                                                                                  


App.PhoneListCtrl.$inject = ['$scope']                                                    
angular.module('app.controllers', []).controller('phoneListCtrl', App.PhoneListCtrl)
```

my test is as follows:

```
 'use strict'                                  
 # jasmine specs for controllers go here                                                                            
 describe 'phoneCat app', ->                                
     beforeEach module('app.controllers')                   

     describe 'phoneListCtrl', ->                           
         it 'should create "phones" model with 3 phones', ->
            scope = {}                                     
            ctrl = App.PhoneListCtrl(scope)                
            expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(3)
```

When I use this controller in the browser it will run just fine so I'm a bit at a lost.
what is the undefined here?
when I dont use the

> App

namespace, everything just works fine.
namespace

Comment: why are you trying to put the controller into the app namespace?

Comment: because I dont want the controller in the global namespace. I could do this App.PhoneListCtrl = class PhoneListCtrl but that way it comes both in the global namespace and in the App namespace

Comment: You shouldn't be using `'use strict'`, this is CoffeeScript, not JavaScript.

Comment: Ok you are right about that but it doesnt hurt the execution of my code infact when compiled to JavaScript it will be included in the file and is very much of use there.